# Excel - Calculate the maximum difference between data

Tags: excel

Good evening !
I am wondering if Excel provides a built-in function that can calculate the maximum of the difference of a list of data.

For example, we have 1, 2, 3, 2, 1. The maximum difference is 2 (3 - 1).
I know how to make this function with a formula, but if Excel provides something to do that directly, that would be interesting.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this:

```
Max(data_scope) - Min(data_scope)
```

Comment: i was dumb... Thanks for putting back on rails :)

Comment: I thought there maybe is a single built-in function that calculates the range, but [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx) I've found nothing. I assume such a function doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, it is done with two standard function so I guess they didn't bother. Thanks Krzysztov !